# htmlAttributes: How do I add a CSS class rule for the below?

Tags: css, model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-2

I want to add a css class statement like below:

`<%: Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Comments, new { @class = "lookandfeel_1" })%>`

to this line:

`<%: Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Money, String.Format("{0:F}", Model.Money)) %>`

How do I do it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try decorating the property with the Display Format attribute:

```
//Your view object
[DisplayFormat( DataFormatString= "{0:F}" )]
public Double Money { get; set; }

//Your view code
<%: Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Money,  new { @class = "lookandfeel_1" }) %>
```

If you are using Entity Framework or similar you will need to do the following to add the metadata attributes:

```
    using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

    namespace MyNameSpace
    {

        [MetadataType(typeof(MetaDataProduct))]
        public partial class MyEntityClass
        {

        }

        public class MetaDataProduct
        {       
           [DisplayName("Price")]
           [DisplayFormat( DataFormatString= "{0:F}" )]
           public int Money{ get; set; }
        }
    }
```